# Save CGImage to PNG file with alpha values intact

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-graphics

I have an array of bytes representing RGBA values that I want to save to file as an image (e.g. a PNG file).

I have some very simple code that almost achieves what I need:

```swift
let data:CGDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(NSData(bytes: rawDataOut, length: rawDataOut.count))!
let bitmapInfo:CGBitmapInfo = [CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrderDefault, CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.Last.rawValue)]
let result:CGImage = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), bitmapInfo, data, nil, false, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)!
let image:UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: result)
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
```

But I am loosing information, i.e. the resulting PNG file shows the image rendered onto a white background and is thus no longer transparent. For example the first four bytes of my byte array are all `0x00` (a black transparent pixel) but in the resulting PNG it is a white opaque pixel.

How do I save the pixel array to PNG with opacity information intact?

Comment: Just a punt, what happens if you use:

let bitmapInfo:CGBitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo.AlphaInfoMask

Comment: This happens: "CGImageCreate: invalid image alphaInfo: 31"

Comment: Hmmm, okay, dunno about this one at all - reading https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGBitmapInfo , maybe ByteOrder32Big will work better for you, not sure what ByteOrderDefault does.